# How to perform this regex replacement more effectively in python without repeating the search?

Tags: python, regex

In python, I want to search for a pattern in a given line and surround it with the html tags. I am doing it as follows:

```
pattern = "(boy|girl)"
line = "I am a boy"

m = re.search(pattern, line)
line = re.sub(pattern, "<strong><u>"+m.group(0)+"</u></strong>", line)
```

But I feel like I am repeating the search twice. In other words, I feel like I should be able to accomplish in one line, but I just don't know the right command yet in python.

Is there something like "&" from perl? that you can use to do something like:

```
s/pattern/<tag>&</tag>/;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
line = re.sub(pattern, r'<strong><u>\1</u></strong>', line)
```

The `\1` is the key part -- it's replaced by the text that matched the pattern.  (the `r` prefix is recommended in all RE patterns to keep backslash escapes as literals).

Comment: @AvinashRaj: In the question, the pattern is `(boy|girl)`, which includes capturing parentheses.

Comment: @BrenBarn - The OP edited his question and changed his pattern entirely.  This invalidated both my answer and Avinash Raj's.

Comment: weird, SO isn't showing me the Q as being edited at all -- maybe it hides edits if they happen very soon?  I saw the pattern as `(boy|girl)` from the start and answered on that basis.

Comment: @AlexMartelli - If the edits are done within the first 5 minutes of asking (which they were), they fall within the grace period and are not recorded.